# iPhone App Validation Failing because of iPad icon.png

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am not sure why this error is being thrown when my application is validated for submission. My application is marked as iPhone application with icon.png as 57 X 57. The error says: iPad:icon.png icon dimensions (57X57) don't meet the size requirements. The icon must be 72X72 pixels, in .png format.

Comment: You need an iPad icon even if you don't target iPads.

Comment: In my old app I just had one 57 X 57 icon.

Answer (score 2):

i think because your application it's a universal application and so you should provide the same icon in different size and fill the plist in the proper way.

1. iphone/ipod
2. iphone 4
3. ipad

I usually use this psd template: http://www.nightlion.net/web/2010/iphone-4-ipad-icon-design-psd-template/

Comment: It was set as iphone/ipad app so I changed to iphone only but still getting the same error!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html

I would just supply all of those icons to cover all the cases (Retina display, etc.)

Comment: But my app is not a universal app it is an iPhone app. I am not sure why it is asking for iPad icons.

Comment: They may be requiring this now because any iPhone app will run on the iPad and the icons will have to be scaled up and won't look very good. Like I say, I'd just design your icons in 512x512 then export them at all the different resolutions.

Comment: I found the problem. I edited the project settings and specified the iPhone device but did not edited the target. I always thought that project settings are the same as target I guess they are NOT. I changed the target and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I edited the project settings and specified the iPhone device but did not edited the target. I always thought that project settings are the same as target I guess they are NOT. I changed the target and it worked fine.

Comment: Target settings override project settings, if you define a setting in the target. You must have previously changed the target settings.